# Differential forms and vector calculus

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let

$0$-form $f =$ function $f$

$1$-form $\alpha^{1} =$ covariant expression for a vector $\bf{A}$

Then consider the following dictionary of symbolic identifications of expressions expressed in the language of differential forms on a manifold and expressions expressed in the language of vector calculus in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

$i_{\bf{v}}(\alpha^{1}) \iff \bf{v}\cdot{\bf{A}}$

$df \iff \text{grad}f$

---

Now, with $\alpha^{1} = a_{i}dx^{i}$,

why is $\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}(a_{i}dx^{i})\iff\text{grad}({\bf{v\cdot{A}}})\cdot{d\bf{x}}$

and not $\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}(a_{i}dx^{i})\iff\text{grad}({\bf{v\cdot{A}}})$?

---

**Edit to my answer:**

$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{C}{\bf{A}\cdot{dx}}$

$\iff \frac{d}{dt}\int_{C(t)}{a_{1}dx^{1}+a_{2}dx^{2}+a_{3}dx^{3}}$

$= \frac{d}{dt}\int_{C(t)}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \frac{d}{dt}\int_{W(t)}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{W(t)} \mathcal{L}_{X}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{W(t)} \mathcal{L}_{{\bf{v}}+\partial / \partial t}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{W(t)} \mathcal{L}_{{\bf{v}}}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)+\mathcal{L}_{\partial / \partial t}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{W(t)} \mathcal{L}_{\bf{v}}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right) + \left(\sum\limits_{i}\frac{\partial a^{i}}{\partial t}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{W(t)} \left(\sum\limits_{i}\frac{\partial a^{i}}{\partial t}dx^{i}\right) + i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)+\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{C(t)} \left(\sum\limits_{i}\frac{\partial a^{i}}{\partial t}dx^{i}\right) + i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)+\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$= \int_{C} \left(\sum\limits_{i}\frac{\partial a^{i}}{\partial t}dx^{i}\right) + i_{\bf{v}}\textbf{d}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)+\textbf{d}i_{\bf{v}}\left(\sum\limits_{i}a_{i}dx^{i}\right)$

$\iff \int_{C}\left[\frac{\partial {\bf{A}}}{\partial t}-{\bf{v}}\times \text{curl}{\bf{A}}+\text{grad}({\bf{v\cdot{A}}})\right]\cdot{d\bf{x}}$

In order for there to be an integration variable in the final line, there must be the integration variable $d{\bf{x}}$, but the integration variable is not supposed to be there, right?

Comment: I haven't tried to figure out your notation, but a simple way to keep things straight are: **(1)** "Vector" (e.g. as in a "vector valued function", or the "direction" part of a "directional derivative") means column vector. **(2)** The derivative of a vector-valued function (of one variable) is again a column vector. **(3)** The derivative of a multivariable function is a row vector. (of a multivariable vector-valued function is a row of columns -- i.e. a matrix) **(4)** differential forms correspond to row vectors.

Comment: Note that since the difference between row and column vectors is usually neglected when this stuff is taught, there is a lot of disagreement about what, for example, the "gradient" actually means -- some people will take it to mean the derivative of $f$ (and thus a row vector), and others prefer to apply the metric transpose to get a column vector. (if you use the dot product, the "metric transpose" is just the ordinary transpose operation)

Answer (score 1):

The gradient on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field and so you need to transform $\operatorname{grad}(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A})$ into a one-form.

If $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \dots, X_n)$ is a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you can identify it with a one-form $X_1 dx^1 + \dots X_n dx^n$ which you can write as $\mathbf{X} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$ if you insist.

Comment: But consider $\textbf{d}i_{\textbf{v}}(a_{i}dx^{i})=\textbf{d}i_{\textbf{v}}(\alpha^{1})$. Now, $\alpha^{1}$ is a one-form, and $i_{\bf{v}}\alpha^{1}=\alpha^{1}(\bf{v})$ is a scalar, therefore $\textbf{d}i_{\textbf{v}}(\alpha^{1})=\textbf{d}(\text{scalar})$ is a one-form. On the other hand, $\text{grad}({\bf{v}}\cdot{\bf{A}})\cdot{dx}$ is  a scalar. You see my conundrum?

Comment: That's because it is bad notation. You shouldn't interpret the second $\cdot$ in $\operatorname{grad}(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A}) \cdot d \mathbf{x}$ as a dot product of two vector-like quantities that should result in a scalar but in the way I wrote in my answer (so the result is a one-form). In more common notation, this operation is denoted by $\operatorname{grad}(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{A})^{\flat}$.

Comment: see my edit, please!

Comment: @failexam: I have no idea what you mean... According to the exterior calculus point of view, you can integrate only forms ("things that have $dx^i$'s inside them"). In order to transform a vector field $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ into a one-form (for example, to do a path integral), you multiply each $X_i$ by $dx^i$ and sum up. The result $X_1 dx^1 + \dots + X_n dx^n$ is a one-form which you can integrate.

Comment: Oh, so you mean that the final line of my equations in the edit is still in exterior calculus and not in vector calculus?

Comment: You already do that by writing $\int_C \text{bla bla bla} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$. This way, the integrand (including the $d \mathbf{x}$!) is a one-form.